# В приведенной форме изложения какой падеж уместнее?

Tags: падежи

Какая форма изложения верная?

*Не стараясь подмечать признаков / не стараясь подмечать признаки*

Родительный/винительный?

Answer (score 1):

[**подмеча́ть**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/165926/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), несов., перех.
ПОДМЕ́ТИТЬ, -ме́чу, -ме́тишь; -ме́ченный; сов., **кого-что**. Заметить, увидеть (мало заметное). *Подмечать недостатки.*

Дело в том, что отрицание ***НЕ*** относится к деепричастию ***стараясь***, а не к глаголу.
Сравните: ***НЕ стараясь*** подмечать признаки — *стараясь **НЕ подмечать** признаков/признаки.*

Думаю, что здесь "работает" вот это правило Розенталя.
Постановка **прямого** дополнения в форме винительного падежа **обязательна** в тех случаях, когда отрицание «не» стоит не при переходном глаголе, а при другом слове в предложении, например: ***не*** очень **люблю** живопись, **не** часто **читаю** художественную литературу.

Я бы написала так: **не стараясь подмечать признаки** (или *стараясь не подмечать признаков* (книжн.); или *стараясь не подмечать признаки* (разг.); или *не подмечая признаков*).

*Итак, петляя по улочкам, **не стараясь найти краткий путь**,  продвигаюсь в сторону мечети Фатиха и дохожу до акведука.*

[§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm) (п. 5)

Comment: Всё верно, частица НЕ не умеет действовать на расстоянии, об этом еще Пушкин говорил.

Answer (score 0):

С ***отрицанием*** родительный падеж вполне уместен. Но если речь о ***конкретных*** признаках и дальше идёт пояснение или их перечисление, тогда лучше выбрать *винительный падеж.*

А вообще, к сожалению, есть тенденция постепенного вытеснения родительного падежа винительным.

---

***Дополнение*** (не обязательное к прочтению)

Нашёл [пример](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E6%E4%E0%EB%20%E4%FF%E4%E8) 1740 года (***внимание:*** текст не очень приятный, мягко скажем, поэтому привожу маленький кусочек):

> ...и Шибарша ***ждал дяди*** своего и не дождался...

Как видно из этого примера, в то время со словом *"ждать"* даже *одушевлённые* существительные ставили в родительный падеж. Не факт, конечно, что он был единственным вариантом для них.